# C# strange code

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

```
Anyone know what follow code does?
```

the question is about follow operators: & and |,and 0xfc

```
    salt[0] = (byte)((salt[0] & 0xfc) | (saltLen & 0x03));
    salt[1] = (byte)((salt[1] & 0xf3) | (saltLen & 0x0c));
    salt[2] = (byte)((salt[2] & 0xcf) | (saltLen & 0x30));
    salt[3] = (byte)((salt[3] & 0x3f) | (saltLen & 0xc0));
```

Comment: You do realize there is a comment directly above those lines explaining what it does?

Comment: Exactly what are you confused about? If you are confused about the code or the comment, can you elaborate as to what is confusing you?

Comment: the question is about follow operators: & and |,and 0xfc

Comment: ozsenegal: Can you add that to your original question? Perhaps trim out some of the code that you don't need to ask it, too? Right now, your question is way too vague and ambiguous to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the comment above explains what it's doing, but if you're looking for a breakdown of the operators:

1. Perform a bitwise `and` on
   `salt[i]` and a hex number (the `&` operator).
2. Perform a bitwise `and` on `salt[i]`
   and a second hex number.
3. Perform a bitwise `or` on the result of steps 1 and 2 (the `|` operator).
4. Cast the result of step 3 to a `byte`
5. Store the result in `salt[i]`

The result is what is noted in the comment block. The numbers of the format `0xc0` and whatnot are in hexadecimal, which is base 16. I.e. `c0` in hex is equivalent to `16*12 + 16*0 = 192` in decimal. In hex, since you run out of digits at 9, you begin using letters. Thus, a=10, b=11, c=12, d=13, e=14, f=15, and f becomes the highest "digit" since you would move over by one place when you get to 16 (as 16 is the base).

See also:

- [Bitwise operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)
- [Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Answer (score 3):

> the question is about follow operators: & and |,and 0xfc

- `&` is the bitwise and operator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx.
- `|` is the bitwise or operator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx.
- `0xfc` isn't an operator, it's an integer constant (i.e., a number). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(VS.71).aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Split salt length (always one byte) into four two-bit pieces and
// store these pieces in the first four bytes of the salt array.
```

This is a cocky answer, but my intention is to indicate that it is already answered, so please let me know if you need more detail :)

Comment: Presumably he meant to ask how it does it, not what it does. Of course, why it does it is the more interesting question.